# Абстрактный класс для копирования объекта и указатель для него

Tags: c++

т.к. базовый класс - абстрактный, то для создания объекта используем указатель и `void show() { cout << ptr[i] }` выводит адрес элемента, а не его значение. При попытке вывести на экран `*ptr[i]` естественно возникает ошибка:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream'(aka 'basic_ostream') and 'Obj')

как можно привести типы?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Obj { public: virtual Obj* clone() = 0; };

class IntObj : public Obj {
    int element;
public:
    IntObj(){};
    IntObj (int temp) { element = temp; }
    Obj* clone() { return new IntObj(element); }
};

class DoubleObj : public Obj {
    double element;
public:
    DoubleObj(){};
    DoubleObj (double temp) { element = temp; }
    Obj* clone() { return new DoubleObj(element); }
};

class StringObj : public Obj {
    string element;
public:
    StringObj(){};
    StringObj (string temp) { element = temp; }
    Obj* clone() { return new StringObj(element); }
};

class Stack {
    Obj **ptr;
    int size = 1;
public:
    Stack() { ptr = new Obj*[size]; }

    Stack(const Stack &s) {
        size = s.getSize();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            *ptr[i] = s.getPtr()[i];
    }

    ~Stack() { delete [] ptr; }

    Obj *getPtr() const { return *ptr; }
    int getSize() const { return size; }

    void push(Obj *obj) {
        Obj** ptrTemp = new Obj*[size];

        ptr[size - 1] = obj->clone();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            ptrTemp[i] = ptr[i];

        delete [] ptr;

        size++;

        ptr = new Obj*[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            ptr[i] = ptrTemp[i];

        delete [] ptrTemp;
    }

    void del () {
        Obj** ptrTemp = new Obj*[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            ptrTemp[i] = ptr[i];

        delete [] ptr;

        size--;

        ptr = new Obj*[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            ptr[i] = ptrTemp[i];

        delete [] ptrTemp;
    }

    Obj* pop() {
        if (size > 1) {
            Obj *temp;
            temp = ptr[size - 2];
            del();
            return temp;
        } else  {
            cout << "Стек был пуст.\n";
            delete [] ptr;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    void show() {
        if (size > 1) {
            cout << "Печать стека: ";

            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                cout << ptr[i] << " ";

            cout << "\n";
        } else
            cout << "Стек пуст.\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Stack i;
    Obj *ai = new IntObj(5);
    IntObj *bi = dynamic_cast<IntObj*>(ai);
    i.push(bi);
    i.show();

    Stack d;
    Obj *ad = new DoubleObj(5.0);
    DoubleObj *bd = dynamic_cast<DoubleObj*>(ad);
    d.push(bd);
    d.show();

    Stack s;
    Obj *as = new StringObj("aaa");
    StringObj *bs = dynamic_cast<StringObj*>(as);
    s.push(bs);
    s.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Что значит "как можно привести типы"? Могли бы человеческим языком изъясняться?

Comment: @Dialogue Перегрузите `operator<<` для своих классов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете объявить виртуальные функции в производных классах следующим образом

```
IntObj* clone() { return new IntObj(element); }
DoubleObj* clone() { return new DoubleObj(element); }
StringObj* clone() { return new StringObj(element); }
```

И тогда проблем у вас не будет, если вы еще объявите виртуальными те функции, которые собираетесь вызывать для каждого созданного объекта.

Вот вам демонстрационная программа, которую вы можете использовать в качестве образца для реализации вашей программы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Obj 
{ 
public: 
    virtual Obj* clone() const = 0; 
    virtual std::ostream & out( std::ostream & ) const = 0;
    virtual ~Obj() {}
};

class IntObj : public Obj 
{
    int element;
public:
    IntObj(){};
    IntObj (int temp) { element = temp; }
    IntObj* clone() const { return new IntObj(element); }
    std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const
    {
        return os << element;
    }        
};

class DoubleObj : public Obj {
    double element;
public:
    DoubleObj(){};
    DoubleObj (double temp) { element = temp; }
    DoubleObj* clone() const { return new DoubleObj(element); }
    std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const
    {
        return os << element;
    }        
};

class StringObj : public Obj {
    std::string element;
public:
    StringObj(){};
    StringObj ( const std::string &temp ) { element = temp; }
    StringObj* clone() const { return new StringObj(element); }
    std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const
    {
        return os << element;
    }        
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Obj &obj )
{
    return obj.out( os );
}

int main() 
{
    Obj * a[3];

    a[0] = IntObj( 10 ).clone();
    a[1] = DoubleObj( 10 ).clone();
    a[2] = StringObj( "10" ).clone();

    for ( Obj *p : a ) std::cout << *p << std::endl;

    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
10
10
10
```

Все, что вам остается, это корректно реализовать свой стек.